# How to secure account creation via (private) API?

Tags: security, api

Some time ago, it was commonplace for smartphone apps to open a browser to a registration page with a CAPTCHA, or to require separate signup via web, because API signup was seen as vulnerable.

Now most apps seem to offer registration via native form, though endpoints for this are usually not documented in their public API. I haven't seen many reports of this being abused to create spam accounts.

How is this done? Is there a standard crypto/handshake process to verify real signups, or does signup typically rely on undocumented endpoints and simple API key passing?

Comment: you could use Wireshark and look if they use API keys or encryption or similar.

Comment: I guess I can spoof the appropriate SSL cert and sniff the registration traffic with Charles while sharing the connection, but I found it puzzling that there's not really any documentation on this subject out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding yields a better experience but has the issue you mention. Yes, the service owners on the other end are still worried about this and combating the problem. And undocumented APIs don't help and the service owners know this.

One of the tools in the toolbox these days is keys assigned to devices which can be used for throttling. This would essentially let you limit the amt of service that can be consumed on a per device basis and it would require you have a device (or can steal the key from one) in order to provide service. So long as the process to issue keys to new devices is strong (a solvable problem) then you can offer a CAPTCHA-free signup experience within the confines of what you are willing to give to a device.

I'd also note that there are other well known approaches you can use, like IP throttling and handshakes with other service providers (like a phone carrier). Depending upon the problem domain these are on the table too...

Comment: Eric, that makes sense -- I am guessing people throttled by UDID while that was available. We can likely still limit signups by MAC address or similar.

Comment: They are unfortunately spoofable and the bad guys have gotten good at figuring these things out.